# How do I tell fabric which role current site has?

Tags: python, fabric

I have just one command in fabfile.py:

```
@role('dev')
def test():
    local('...')
```

Now, I can use `--role=dev` in every command, but this is extremely stupid.

What I want is to install my project in a host once, with a certain role, then use it without repeating this parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically include the following in my fabfile.py:

```
if not len(env.roles):
    env.roles = ["test"]
```

This says if env.roles is not defined (via the command line for instance) that it should be defined as "test" in my case. So in your case I would alter the above to substitute `dev` for `test` and thus you would have:

```
if not len(env.roles):
    env.roles = ["dev"]
```

By doing this you should find that you get the behavior you are looking for while providing you the ability to override if you so desire at any point in the future.

EDIT: I'm editing this to include a small example fabfile.py and explanation of usage.

```
env.roledefs = {
    'test': ['test.fabexample.com'],
    'stage': ['stage.fabexample.com'],
    'prod': ['web01.fabexample.com', 'web02.fabexample.com', 'web03.fabexample.com'],
}
# default role will be test
env.roles = ['test']

def git_pull():
    run("git pull")

def deploy():
    target = "/opt/apps/FOO"
    with cd(target):
        git_pull()
    sudo("service apache2 restart")
```

Now this fabfile will allow me to deploy code to any of **three** different environments: "test", "stage", or "prod". I select which environment I want to deploy to via the command line:

```
fab -R stage deploy
```

or,

```
fab --role=stage deploy
```

If I **do not** specify a role fabric will default to 'test' due to `env.roles` being set. Not that fabric isn't used to do anything to the local box, instead it acts on the local box (or boxes) as defined in `env.roledefs` although with some modifications it could be made to work locally as well.

Typically the fabric command is used from a development box to perform these operations remotely on the testing, staging, or production boxes, therefore specifying the role via the command line is not "extremely stupid" but is by design in this case.

Comment: But you have to edit the file for each instance. This means merging incoming changesets every time.

Comment: I'm not certain why you think you have edit the file.  Perhaps you could clarify your workflow a bit as that may help illuminate why you feel that way.

Comment: I mean several instances of the project will be 'dev', another one 'test', 'stage', and one will be 'prod'. All of them exchange code over version control. So there has to be the same fabfile.py, and a role file that's ignored by version control.

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure that fabric fits the workflow that you are are attempting to make use of.  I would recommend you use fabric from a central box, either a build box or from your development platform.  From there you can deploy using fabric to any environment you have defined in your fabfile.  For example, in my case I have a development machine (my laptop), a test server, a stage server, and a production server.  In my fabfile I have each of these listed in env.roledefs as "test", "stage", and "prod" with the corresponding host.  When I want to deploy I specify the role on the command line.

Comment: Fabric then performs the tasks outlined in it's configuration for the host that matches the role I specified.  The fabfile is in my git repository and thus it gets distributed to each server in the way I'm deploying, but that's not absolutely necessary.  Perhaps we can figure out a way to make your workflow better match this scenario, or perhaps your workflow is set and we can rethink a better solution for you.

Comment: I have edited my answer in hopes that it helps clear things up on the usage of fabric.

Comment: Thanks. As I see, fabric is used to push code and deploy remotely, but not for local things. Right?

Comment: You **can** do things locally with it, in fact I have written my scripts to perform actions that work both locally or remotely, but generally yes, it is used to push code.  The `run()` and `sudo()` commands work on remote systems while the `local()` command works similar to `run()` only on the local system and there is no real equivalent to `sudo()` for the local system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [env.roledefs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/usage/execution.html#roles) to associates roles with groups of hosts.